# Why is my DIVs going on top of each other?

Tags: html, css

[Link to my site. Go to under any bracelets page and see the glitch, especially on phone.](https://jewelbeadsbracelets.om)
The product displays will be in each other. The only weird thing is that if you refresh the page, it turns into its normal state... Anyone got any propositions please let me know! I've been working on this for the past few weeks and this seems to be the only bug. Someone on a similar forum instructed me to do some things yet that still didn't even work...

```css
.product {
  width: calc(100%/4 - 40px);
  margin-bottom: 59px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 20px;
}

.product_image {
  width: 100%;
}

.product_image img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.product_grid {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0 -20px;
}

.product_content {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 36px;
  padding-bottom: 38px;
}

.product_title a {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #1b1b1b;
  line-height: 1.1;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 200ms ease;
  -ms-transition: all 200ms ease;
  -o-transition: all 200ms ease;
  transition: all 200ms ease;
}

.product_title a:hover {
  color: #e95a5a;
}

.product_price {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #6c6a74;
  line-height: 0.75;
  margin-top: 13px;
}

.product_extra {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 54px;
  width: 66px;
  height: 36px;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
  -moz-transform-origin: top left;
  -ms-transform-origin: top left;
  -o-transform-origin: top left;
  transform-origin: top left;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.product_extra a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  line-height: 36px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">

    <div class="product_grid">

      <!-- Product -->
      <div class="product">
        <div class="product_image"><img src="Products/spectrum/details_1.png" alt="Spectrum"></div>
        <div class="product_content">
          <div class="product_title"><a href="spectrum.html">Spectrum</a></div>
          <div class="product_price">$8.99</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Product -->
      <div class="product">
        <div class="product_image"><img src="Products/wave_black/details_1.png" alt="Black Wave"></div>
        <div class="product_content">
          <div class="product_title"><a href="wave_black.html">Black Wave Charm</a></div>
          <div class="product_price">$6.99</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**EDIT, THE PROBLEM:**
[image: Here's an example]

**SUPPOSED TO LOOK LIKE:**
[image: This is what it's supposed to look like:]

Comment: how many products do you want to display in a single column? I will prefer to use bootstrap grid.

Comment: @waqasMumtaz Thank you so much for helping. I'm still at a loss. I need to include 4 product in a row and 3 columns. You can see on my website in the description. Also, I'll edit this post so you can see exactly what I'm talking about.

Comment: @waqasMumtaz do you want bootstrap.min.css / boostrap.min.js / popper.js??

Comment: There is no reason to use things like bootstrap, better to learn basic css by yourself. Depending on your browser support to fix things like this could be as little as 4 rows of css instead of bringing in bootstrap.css and its javascript + a third party lib.

Comment: @Dejan.S I'm mostly well-rounded in css and html. I used ColorLib. to get a html template for my website so I don't have to start from scratch since I don't have the same knowledge like professionals, of course. This bug seems to be the only thing that my website still struggles with. Other than that, everything on my website runs perfectly fine and I'm quite proud of it. So, do you think the bootstrap.css and its js is directly linked to it or can I delete it so I can use css for that (or possibly locate and take it out)?

Comment: I can't reach the site so haven't look what you use bootstrap for. What do you use it for?

Comment: The site: https://jewelbeadsbracelets.com ... Idk it came with it the file from the html template from ColorLib... it’s called Sublime. from their site so you could directly see what I’m talking about. Is there a way I can supply you the bootstrap so u can see?

Comment: By the way In your website, You are already using bootstrap. Let me add a solution using bootstrap

Comment: @waqasMumtaz I'll take any help I can get, thanks! Btw, thank you Dejan for sticking with me ik its aggravating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.product {
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  background-color: #ededed;
}



.product_content {
  padding-top: 36px;
  padding-bottom: 38px;
}

.product_title a {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #1b1b1b;
  line-height: 1.1;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 200ms ease;
  -ms-transition: all 200ms ease;
  -o-transition: all 200ms ease;
  transition: all 200ms ease;
}

.product_title a:hover {
  color: #e95a5a;
}

.product_price {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #6c6a74;
  line-height: 0.75;
  margin-top: 13px;
}

.product_extra {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 54px;
  width: 66px;
  height: 36px;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
  -moz-transform-origin: top left;
  -ms-transform-origin: top left;
  -o-transform-origin: top left;
  transform-origin: top left;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.product_extra a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  line-height: 36px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://jewelbeadsbracelets.com/styles/bootstrap4/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <!-- Product -->
      <div class="product">
        <div class="product_image"><img src="https://www.freevectorpro.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Audi-logo.jpg" alt="Spectrum" class="img-fluid"></div>
        <div class="product_content">
          <div class="product_title"><a href="spectrum.html">Spectrum</a></div>
          <div class="product_price">$8.99</div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
 <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <!-- Product -->
      <div class="product">
        <div class="product_image"><img src="https://www.freevectorpro.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Audi-logo.jpg" alt="Black Wave"  class="img-fluid"></div>
        <div class="product_content">
          <div class="product_title"><a href="wave_black.html">Black Wave Charm</a></div>
          <div class="product_price">$6.99</div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
 <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <!-- Product -->
      <div class="product">
        <div class="product_image"><img src="https://www.freevectorpro.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Audi-logo.jpg" alt="Black Wave"  class="img-fluid"></div>
        <div class="product_content">
          <div class="product_title"><a href="wave_black.html">Black Wave Charm</a></div>
          <div class="product_price">$6.99</div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
 <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <!-- Product -->
      <div class="product">
        <div class="product_image"><img src="https://www.freevectorpro.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Audi-logo.jpg" alt="Black Wave"  class="img-fluid"></div>
        <div class="product_content">
          <div class="product_title"><a href="wave_black.html">Black Wave Charm</a></div>
          <div class="product_price">$6.99</div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <!-- Product -->
      <div class="product">
        <div class="product_image"><img src="https://www.freevectorpro.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Audi-logo.jpg" alt="Black Wave"  class="img-fluid"></div>
        <div class="product_content">
          <div class="product_title"><a href="wave_black.html">Black Wave Charm</a></div>
          <div class="product_price">$6.99</div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

In your website is using bootstrap so you can easily use bootstrap grid and display product in rows and columns. You don't need to create grid by your own. Use bootstrap classes to adjust grid as per screen size. check https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: Hey you're amazing at this! If you look at my website and go under Home>Shop, you'll see that the products are there. When seen on mobile, all 4 boxes are squished together. Do you have a way so they show individually like it used to? You're stellar at coding man!

Comment: How many products do you want to display on mobile screen? 1 product per row ?

Comment: you need to change class='col-3' to class='col-md-3 col-sm-12' I update my answer.

Comment: remove `@media only screen and (max-width: 991px)
.product {
     width: calc((100% - 30px) / 2); 
}` from https://jewelbeadsbracelets.com/styles/categories_responsive.css

Comment: Thank you so much! You're truly amazing. It fixed it. This bug has been there for the past few weeks and I wouldv'e never guessed to use bootstrap. @Dejan. S thank you for the help as well! I really do appreciate it :)))

Comment: Last thing. Do you know how to fix my sorting system now because it doesn't work now. If not, its okay.

Comment: sorry, I am not aware of this.

Comment: @JewelBeads. Welcome :) Kindly upvote my answer, It will help me.

Answer (score 0):

I made just a few modifications, but your code seems seems to work almost out of the box. I basically changed the margins on the grid and product card.

Is this what you are looking for?

```css
.product-grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-left: -20px;
}

.product {
  width: calc(100%/4 - 20px);
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 20px;
  background-color: #ededed;
}

.product_image {
  width: 100%;
}

.product_image img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.product_content {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 36px;
  padding-bottom: 38px;
}

.product_title a {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #1b1b1b;
  line-height: 1.1;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 200ms ease;
  -ms-transition: all 200ms ease;
  -o-transition: all 200ms ease;
  transition: all 200ms ease;
}

.product_title a:hover {
  color: #e95a5a;
}

.product_price {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #6c6a74;
  line-height: 0.75;
  margin-top: 13px;
}

.product_extra {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 54px;
  width: 66px;
  height: 36px;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
  -moz-transform-origin: top left;
  -ms-transform-origin: top left;
  -o-transform-origin: top left;
  transform-origin: top left;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.product_extra a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  line-height: 36px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">

    <div class="product-grid">

      <!-- Product -->
      <div class="product">
        <div class="product_image"><img src="https://www.freevectorpro.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Audi-logo.jpg" alt="Spectrum"></div>
        <div class="product_content">
          <div class="product_title"><a href="spectrum.html">Spectrum</a></div>
          <div class="product_price">$8.99</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Product -->
      <div class="product">
        <div class="product_image"><img src="https://www.freevectorpro.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Audi-logo.jpg" alt="Black Wave"></div>
        <div class="product_content">
          <div class="product_title"><a href="wave_black.html">Black Wave Charm</a></div>
          <div class="product_price">$6.99</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <!-- Product -->
      <div class="product">
        <div class="product_image"><img src="https://www.freevectorpro.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Audi-logo.jpg" alt="Black Wave"></div>
        <div class="product_content">
          <div class="product_title"><a href="wave_black.html">Black Wave Charm</a></div>
          <div class="product_price">$6.99</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <!-- Product -->
      <div class="product">
        <div class="product_image"><img src="https://www.freevectorpro.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Audi-logo.jpg" alt="Black Wave"></div>
        <div class="product_content">
          <div class="product_title"><a href="wave_black.html">Black Wave Charm</a></div>
          <div class="product_price">$6.99</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <!-- Product -->
      <div class="product">
        <div class="product_image"><img src="https://www.freevectorpro.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Audi-logo.jpg" alt="Black Wave"></div>
        <div class="product_content">
          <div class="product_title"><a href="wave_black.html">Black Wave Charm</a></div>
          <div class="product_price">$6.99</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hey thank you so much for the suggestion but the products go into 3 rows and 4 columns instead of 4 colums and 3 rows. Ill upload what it looks like to the post

Comment: @JewelBeads. Have you used my code and made the changes? Because the code works here as you want it to. I can tell that you havent used my code, there is more space then 20px between the products, do you want it to be 40px?

Comment: I used the code and directly replaced it with what I had in the css. I don’t know what the problem is but yea try that. I made the changes and it’s in the post... look at the very bottom image

Comment: @JewelBeads. You don't use the css I have there. Like the product_grid does not have any css. I renamed it to `product-grid` as it is more correct in terms of "bem". Just a side note there, `.product_grid` implies that it is a part of the the product.

Comment: S Omg you're so right. I fixed it and on my live server its fixed but it still has that gray box around .product_content. When I upload it to my website, it goes back to that 4 row 3 column thing again..

Comment: @JewelBeads. remove `background-color: #ededed;` that I added to product. It works fine for me now on your page.

Comment: S Yup it fixed the gray boxes! You're amazing dude!